# sudo: scapy unknown command

Tags: python, ubuntu

Подскажите почему не могу запустить scapy с sudo:

```
~$ sudo scapy
sudo: scapy: command not found
```

, но в то же время просто scapy запускается без проблем.

Местоположение scapy:

```
~$ which scapy
/home/sergey/.local/bin/scapy
```

Содержимое переменной Path:

```
~$ env | grep ^PATH=
PATH=/home/sergey/bin:/home/sergey/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Содержимое env Path:

```
~$ sudo env | grep ^PATH=
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Запускайте программу через sudo с указанием полного пути - `sudo  /home/sergey/.local/bin/scapy`

Comment: Спасибо работает, если полностью прописать путь, а вот как прописать переменную env path  ?

Comment: может, это поможет https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/au-sudo/#6.Securing%20the%20Sudo%20Path|outline